# ¿Cómo abrir el cuadro de diálogo Guardar como en python?

Tags: python, django

Estoy creando una aplicación con django y tengo un reporte que creo en PDF con fpdf, esto trabaja bien, pero me guuarda el archivo en la carpeta de la aplicación. Necesito abrir un cuadro de diálogo Guardar como, para dar la posibilidad de escoger la ruta. Tkinter no me sirve, porque cuando invocas filedialog se abre la ventanita por defecto de tkinter ¿existe algún otro módulo que me permita hacerlo  o implementarlo?

Este es el código de la función en views.py

```
def exportarMarcajes(request):
class PDF(FPDF):
    # Encabezado
    def header(this):
        # Logo
         this.image('imagenes/logo.png', 10, 8, 8)

    # Pie de página
    def footer(this):
        # Posición a 1.5 cm del final
        this.set_y(-15)
        # Arial cursiva 8
        this.set_font('Arial', 'I', 8)
        # Número de página
        hoy = date.today()
        mes = ["enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre",
       "noviembre", "diciembre"]
        txt = f'Reporte generado ({str(hoy.day)} de {mes[hoy.month - 1]} de {str(hoy.year)})  -  Página {str(this.page_no())}/{{nb}}'

        this.cell(0, 10, txt, 0, 0, 'R')

        this.line(10, 271, 205, 271)

datos = Guia.objects.all()

registros = []

for d in datos:
    if len(d.rxObs)>0 or len(d.analObs)>0 or len(d.tcObs)>0:
        gg = [d.guia, d.transito, d.rxObs, d.analObs, d.tcObs]
        registros.append(gg)

# Crear reporte con tamaño de hoja = Carta
reporte = PDF(format="letter")
reporte.alias_nb_pages()
reporte.add_page()

# Define el color de relleno
reporte.set_fill_color(r=238, g=238, b=238)

for myData in registros:
    # Define la fuente (nombre, estilo, tamaño)
    reporte.set_font("Arial", "B", 9)

    texto = "Guía: " + myData[0] + "     Tránsito: " + myData[1]
    # Escribe en el reporte. ln=1 para que escriba un retorno de línea al final
    reporte.cell(195, 4, txt=texto, ln=1, align="L", fill=1)

    if len(myData[2]) > 0:
        reporte.set_font("Arial", "BI", 9)
        reporte.cell(90, 5, txt="Rayos X", ln=1, align="L")
        reporte.set_font("Arial", size=9)
        # A diferencia de cell que escribe una línea, multi_cell escribe un párrafo
        reporte.multi_cell(195, 5, txt=myData[2])
# Escribir el archivo con el nombre seleccionado
nombre = "Marcajes.pdf"
try:
    reporte.output(nombre)
except:
    pass

return redirect('/')
```

Necesito almacenar en la variable nombre, la ruta y el nombre del archivo seleccionados por el usuario.

Comment: Deja tu código, lo que haz hecho, tus errores, así podednos ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 0):

Lo que el método `output` hace es escribir el contenido del archivo como `bytes` al lugar especificado.

```
# https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/blob/master/fpdf/fpdf.py
def output(self, name='',dest=''):
        """Output PDF to some destination
        By default the PDF is written to sys.stdout. If a name is given, the
        PDF is written to a new file. If dest='S' is given, the PDF data is
        returned as a byte string."""
        ...
        elif dest=='F':
            #Save to local file
            with open(name,'wb') as f:
                f.write(buffer)
```

Para guardar el archivo en un lugar distinto, cambia el nombre del archivo para que incluya el lugar donde lo quieres guardar. Por ejemplo:

```
# Esto pondria el documento adentro de una carpeta
# llamada Documentos dentro de la carpeta de la aplicacion
nombre = "Documentos/Marcajes.pdf"
```

Sin embargo, si lo que quieres es que el usuario pueda guardar este documento en su dispositivo personal, considerando que estas creando una aplicacion web, lo que necesitas es o bien ofrecer un enlace al documento apenas creado con [el atributo `download`](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_download.asp), o usar JavaScript para hacer esto de forma automatica.

O talvez esto pueda funcionar.

```
return redirect('/Marcajes.pdf')
```

Dependiendo del efecto que quieras.

Sin embargo, ten cuidado de sanitizar el input del usuario, si planeas usarlo como nombre / ruta del archivo.

[Documentacion de PyFPDF](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/output/index.html)

Comment: Ok, entendido. Muchas gracias.